# How to increase the size of Form.Check of react-bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Following is how I am using the Form.check:

```
<Form.Check
  inline
  disabled={
    this.state.listOfselectedPreview.filter(
      ob => ob.questionId === item.questionId
    ).length > 0
      ? true
      : false
  }
  type="checkbox"
  checked={this.state.listOfsearchselected[index].status}
  onChange={this.handleInputChangeCheckboxlistsearch.bind(this, index)}
/>;
```

it renders as follows:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static" />
</div>;
```

and it displays as normal but I want to increase the size of it.

Can someone point out any CSS?